# Inputting String with two fullstops

Tags: c++, string, input, getline

I need to input a string with two fullstops, but this code dosent input the last fullstop.
When input is:  "The mind is everything. What you think you become." Followed by the enter key and "sitdown"

The program stores : "The mind is everything. What you think you become"  in `tem`, it misses the last fullstop, instead the fullstop is stored in `pas`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std;
int main(){
  char tem[50];
  String pas=""

  cin.get(tem,50);
  cin>>pas;
  cout<<tem<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `two fullstops`: you mean the null character `\0` (`0x00`)?

Comment: @Stefan: ["Full stop"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop) is the British/Commonwealth word for the punctuation mark that in North American English is called a "period", that is, `.` (ASCII ordinal `0x2e`). His example input has two periods, one at the end of each sentence, but the second sentence's period is being dropped.

Answer (score 1):

The size of buffer you allocated is 50 char long, the string you enter is also 50 char long, but `cin.get` needs 1 char for terminating 0 so it eats your period. Make buffer 51 long and read 51 chars.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char tem[51];
    std::cin.get(tem, 51);
    std::cout << tem << std::endl;
}
```

If you use `std::string` instead, you don't need to worry about your input not fitting your buffer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string tem;
    std::getline(std::cin, tem);
    std::cout << tem << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Although why anyone would not declare tem as `string tem;` eludes me.

Comment: @TanveerBadar: I think there are a lot of old books around ;-)

Comment: @TanveerBadar Indeed

Answer (score -1):

The length of this string "The mind is everything. What you think you become." is 50 and array tem is also of size 50 .cin needs null termination ("\0") character at the end of the string. That is why it is not printing second full stop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char tem[51];
    string pas="";
    cin.get(tem,51);
    cout<<tem<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Avoid adding photos like this. The non sighted friends cannot read this.